# App installation failed due to application-identifier entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, entitlements, bundle-identifier

I am unable to install a watchOS 2 WatchKit app due to an application-identifier entitlement. This happened after turning on App Groups in the Capabilities tab.

Full error:

> **App installation failed**
>
> This application's application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade to be allowed.

[image: Screenshot 1]

This is running the app in debug mode on a physical device. Running just the iOS app works fine.

I have turned App Groups off again and removed the entitlements files that were added, but same error.

Comment: Were you able to find the fix?

Comment: Yes, the answer from @john-nesbitt did the trick

Comment: As to 'why' it happens (might be helpful to list), in my case, on developer account change. Was installed on account A and was trying to run after changing to account B. (I do not have entitlement file in the project).

Comment: Check out the second answer first, it is more comprehensive and won't result in data loss.

Comment: A given app has an an app name + bundleId. If you use the same app name, but with a different bundle id, then you'd get this error. That's how I got it! Luckily the solution is simple. Either use the old bundleId. Or delete the old app, so the new app name + bundle-id can work together. As for why it can't just re-install, with old app name-new bundleId, I suppose the entitlements are stored elsewhere and you need to somehow have that entitlement removed from the device. Only then you can install the app with a different bundleId

Answer (score 865, accepted):

I had this problem with an iPhone app, and fixed it using the following steps.

- With your device connected, and Xcode open, select Window->Devices
- In the left tab of the window that pops up, select your problem device
- In the detail panel on the right, remove the offending app from the "Installed Apps" list.

After I did that, my app rebuilt and launched just fine. Since your app is a watchOS app, I'm not sure that you'll have the same result, but it's  worth a try.

Comment: That will erase the app and all it's content. I need to upgrade and not loose all my data in the process if possible.

Comment: Didn't solve for me. I'm stuck even turning off App Groups, deleting entitlements, cleaning and cleaning build folder. Also removed the app and rebooted Apple Watch...

Comment: So you deleted the app

Comment: My app wasn't displayed in the Windows->Devices list, but I deleted it from the phone (by pressing and holding on the icon) which fixed the problem. Thanks John.

Comment: I want to test app migration to the new version, and I can't do that if I delete existing app (AppStore version) from the device.

Comment: Sure that works, but in my case the problem is, that I have to do this every time a different person form the team uses the same device, which is annoying, so deletion isn't a good solution!

Comment: For some reason the app wasn't listed for me. Deleting the app directly on the phone worked though.

Comment: That works. Good.State data for the app was also deleted. Bad.

Comment: check this, if don't want to lost the app data :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43536183/1237937

Comment: Just change Bundle identifier. This is works for me.

Comment: @shurvirpm Change Bundle identifier? Change it to what, exactly?

Comment: For me the app wasn't on the phone, it's a new phone and I last touched the sample app in question nearly 12 months ago, and nothing came up when searching the phone. However, it  was in the Installed Apps list, and deleting it there as described fixed the issue for me! Quite bizarre.

Comment: I had to remove the testflight app

Comment: In my case I was having trouble with imessage app and this was only option to delete it and reinstall it.

Answer (score 115):

I had this problem and was not able to resolve it without deleting and reinstalling the app (messing with provisioning profiles, as some here suggested, did not help).

**However, I did not lose my existing test data.** Here's how to do that, for anyone having this problem in the future:

1. **Before** removing the app, open the Xcode "Devices" window (that's cmd-shift-2).
2. Select your device and find your app in the "Installed Apps" list.
3. Click on the gear icon and select "Download Container...". This will copy all of the app's data to your Mac. Save that somewhere for now.
4. Delete the app and reinstall it from Xcode. Kill the app from Xcode (click the stop button), so it's not running.
5. Back in the "Devices" window, click the gear icon and select "Replace Container...". Select the data that you downloaded to your Mac in step 3.

Xcode will then restore your previously saved app data.
**You now have your old test data back**, and the app should run.

Comment: This works particularly well when using the "automatic provisioning" feature in Xcode 8.

Comment: I truly wish that I had read this before using the answer. Then the state data would have been preserved. (See my comment above).

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Comment: 100% the right answer IF YOU DON'T WANT TO LOSE YOUR DATA. Should be accepted answer.

Comment: I have same scenario but my useful data is in Userdefaults
Can we recover that anyway? Help is appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately you still lose keychain items with this method.

Comment: This is the correct answer!!!
Thanks!!! I avoided to loose about 4 years of data!!!

Comment: OMG, thank you! I almost deleted 7 years of data! Actually i think i have a backup from a year ago but still! Do NOT do John Nesbitt's answer without reading the fine print. Better yet, just do Tom Harrington's.

Answer (score 32):

You will get this error when your AppID prefix does not match the prefix of the previously installed app.  If your app is already in the App Store, you will not be able to submit updates without restoring the original AppID prefix or contacting Apple.

Apple's instructions for handling this problem: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2319/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013778-CH1-ERRORMESSAGES-UPGRADE_S_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER_DOES_NOT_MATCH_THE_INSTALLED_APP

If you did not intend to change the AppID prefix then Xcode is signing your app with the wrong provisioning profile.

If you do intend to change the AppID prefix (because the app was transferred to a new developer, or you are migrating from an old pre-2011 AppID) you must contact Apple to migrate an existing AppID to a new prefix.

You must also add the `previous-application-identifiers` entitlement to your app, listing all previous AppIDs (with old prefixes).  And you must ask Apple to generate a provisioning profile for you that includes the `previous-application-identifiers` entitlement.

Comment: My wildcarded profile that I used for development expired and I mistakenly created an app-specific one. After reading your post, I created a new wildcarded profile and used it. Worked like a charm. Yours is the most accurate post and should be the accepted answer. Deleting the app and losing the data is not a good option for many of us. Thanks!

Comment: `previous-application-identifiers` is not needed anymore. Debug builds won't install, but production builds through Testflight will update automagically. I contacted Apple about this identifier and they were clueless about this old mechanism.

Answer (score 31):

Delete any previous versions of App from your iPhone and then Clean->Build and Run again. Your app should run smoothly on your Device.

Also, please make sure you have not selected Distribution Certificate in your Project Settings while trying to run your project directly on your device.

Answer (score 18):

**I solved this without deleting the app**

With the project open in xcode.
Project -> Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Provisioning Profiles (drop down)
It is probably set to automatic and is choosing the wrong profile.  Open the drop down and choose the correct one, then re-run the app.

Comment: I at first tried deleting and reinstalling the app. Didn't work. Then I scrolled down and saw this answer. The build was failing with this error only for automated UItests but not for the regular build, and it turns out the right provisioning profile was selected for the regular build but not the automated UItests build. So, updating that fixed the problem..

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem and was stuck for several minutes and after a search, the simplest solution that i found is just remove the previously installed app from your device manually and try to run the app from Xcode again.

Hope it helps you. 
 All the Best...

Comment: Yes! If the app is offloaded then you must remove it by hand - won't find it in Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

## Explanation

For me, this issue happened because I have signed in with a different account than the account I have installed the app on the iPhone with.

## Solution

Just delete the app from the iPhone and run it again from Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

Steps

1. With your device connected, and Xcode open, select Window->Devices
2. Now select the app and download the container using setting icon
3. Delete the app
4. Install app again using Xcode
5. Stop from Xcode
6. Go to Window->Device and select the app and replace the container that is backup from previous app

Comment: Container steps are not necessary but nice if you wish to maintain the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by App ID prefix, when you switching different developer accounts. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2311/_index.html for Apple's support.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few thing myself like updating/making new provisioning profiles, fixing entitlements in Apple Member Center and in project but in my case, I simply had to delete the application and re-run it.

o_O

---

> This application's application-identifier entitlement does not match
>   that of the installed application.

NOTE: it says "*...does not match the installed application*"

I guess it happened for me because we added a new app extension and there must have been some target related migration issues? Not sure but anyways

Comment: yes, delete the installed app in your device and re-run from Xcode. I had this problem because I added a target in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I had accidentally changed the provisioning profile to have a wildcard in it.

Ie., it went from com.companyname.appnickname to com.companyname.*

I made a new provisioning profile with the full name correctly named, downloaded it, set the Target->build settings->provisioning profile to that new profile, restarted xcode, got a bizarre error from xcode (it seemed to confuse my various app developer logins), restarted xcode again, and it worked!

I didn't want to delete the existing app, because I was trying to test what happens when a user upgraded their app to a newer version, so I had installed the app store version and then run my xcode with the newer version (which acts like 'upgrading' the app without removing any user data).

Comment: You just need to make sure you are using the same Provisioning profile you originally built the app with.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I solved it by changing Bundle Identifier to something new. After that it build project with no problem.

My steps:

- Open Xcode
- Go to General tab
- Find Identity
- Change Bundle Identifier to something new.

[image: Bundle identifier change]

Comment: This doesn't work if you would like to test an app update.

Comment: By changing the bundle ID, you've effectively created a brand new app.

Answer (score 2):

This happened when I tried installing over top of an adhoc build.

Answer (score 2):

In most of the responses to this issue, there's one critical aspect being overlooked that was brought up by the original asker. The app needs to be installed without deleting the existing install. In my case, the app uses an SQLite database that stores quite a bit of data for the user. Obviously, if you delete the app, then you delete the data. A solution that allowed me to test it in the same way a user will update it was a must.

In my case, the issue was Xcode using a provisioning profile automatically generated by Xcode. This probably happened because I got a new computer and didn't transfer the distribution provisioning profile over. Not to mention, I had not updated the app in almost 2 years. So my original provisioning profile (which contains the Entitlements application-identifier) was long gone. Solution: in Xcode preferences-> Accounts-> Select the appropriate Apple ID-> View Details-> Under Provisioning Profiles, right-click on the Xcode-generated profile for that app (it's prefixed with XC iOS), and select Move to Trash.

[image: Xcode provisioning profiles under Accounts]

On the developer website, create a new distribution profile with your App's ID. Download the new profile, double click and Xcode should automatically install it. Conversely, you could return to the profiles listed in Xcode and tap the Download button next to your newly created profile. Build the app and try running again. By the way, my Xcode is set to automatically manage code signing, which other than this issue works great.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The bundle.identifier and the name of the project has to be the same. At least that was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error until I restored the watch to factory defaults as per https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17948

"Apparently if you have and existing WatchOS 1 app and try to update it to WatchOS 2 the bundle identifier changes and causes this error. If you update your watch you will need to do reset it if you had installed  WatchOS1 app before updating that app to WatchOS2."

Comment: I also had to restore the watch to factory defaults. Had tried all the other relevant suggestions, but to no avail. Had also regenerated all the provisioning profiles to make sure they were consistent with the entitlements. My situation was just as described here: Had an existing WatchOS 1 app, that I was trying to update to WatchOS 2.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I followed some few logical steps: uninstall app, rebuild project, the only solution that worked for me was: **restart XCode**. (XCode 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR - delete the app from the device and run again.

In my case :
 1. I compiled and **run** the app on the iPhone **device**.
 2. I open in the setting the **Capabilities** and turn on the **iCloud**
 3. Then I try to run the app again, boom, error : "App installation failed
This application's application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade to be allowed.

4.Then I **deleted** to app from the iPhone (after I read the answers here)
5.Everything works O.K

Answer (score 1):

For the people who might be part of more than one team, this can be your problem:

- If the app's bundle id is hard coded in your Info.plist then Xcode can get confused and throw this tantrum.

To fix:

- Make sure that the bundle id is set as:

  $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

Answer (score 1):

A given app has an an app name + bundleId. If you use the same app name, but with a different bundle id, then you'd get this error. That's how I got it!

Luckily the solution is simple. Either:

- use the old bundleId.
- delete the old app, so the new app name + bundle-id can work together.

As for why it can't just re-install, with old app name-new bundleId, I *suppose* the entitlements are stored elsewhere and you need to somehow have that entitlement removed from the device. Only then you can install the app with a different bundleId

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. To make it work I had to reset the Apple Watch to the last available backup.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the main iPhone app, Watch app and build them again solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error after I moved from a 5s to a 6s.
I recovered the new 6s from a backup of the old iPhone.
Because of this on the new iPhone the old app was installed.

The old app did not show up in the 6s "Installed Apps" list!
I manually deleted this old app from the 6s and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue because I built to the phone with my code signing turned off from another machine, so you need to uninstall the app from the phone before installing/building to the phone with code signing on.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and resolving it by just changing the **Display Name** and **Bundle Identifier** from the previous App that also installed on my iPhone.
Steps:

```
Xcode -> General tab -> Find Identity -> Change Bundle Identifier
```

So, now I have two same Apps with same functionality but with two different names and identity.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of the certificate.

because my own certificate to sign the app wasn't part of the developper team (new employee), upgrading the app from the App Store to a new version wasn't allow.

So in case it happen to you and you can't manage to obtain a "good" certificate, just clone the git appStore version, open two Xcode projects, compile the old version, update the settings as you wish, the compile the new one and you're done.

a little bit dirty and tricky but I hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the App ID in combination with the certificate used to create the provisioning profiles.  None of my provisioning profiles were working because none of them were "Elgible" (created with a certificate that matched the App ID). I had moved development to a new machine, so perhaps this was the deeper reason.  At any rate I had to create a new certificate, then new provisioning profiles with that certificate being careful to choose the right App ID when creating them.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me.
My problem: I had installed an App Version from Testflight, so, I just deleted both, the old app and the Testflight version, and is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting the pending agreements from the developer website and iTunes Connect website and reopening the project in X-Code solved the situation for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this occurred after updating to XCode 11,
like the others have said, it is a signing issue.
What fixed it for me was to go to Developer portal > Certificates & Identifiers
Edit the provisioning profile you are using

[List of certificates Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYMVD.png)

You'll see that there's certificate for XCode 11 (as seen on screenshot)
Just tick that box, re download the profile, and update your projects signing with the new profile.

Answer (score 0):

With MacOS Catalina, your iPhone will be displayed in the 'Locations' sidebar of Finder windows (as long as you've got the Finder preferences set up to show external devices) - you can then access the files via the 'Files' option which is available from the bar near the top of the window, just below the title (in my case I had to click the '>' at the right).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what finally fixed it for me (Xcode 11). Ran into this issue running Apple's sample project "CoreDataCloudKitDemo" (WWDC 2019 session 202).

I unchecked the "Mac" deployment option in the project's "General" settings, and kept "Automatically manage signing". Now that it was an iPhone/iPad app, the error went away and I could build.

I then re-checked the "Mac" option, and Xcode asked it it should do it's magic to manage entitlements, etc.; I agreed, and Xcode resolved all the issues, and I was able to build the Mac version.

Answer (score 0):

My solution solved the problem in just 2 steps and without losing data or need to uninstall app.

1. Download the provisioning profile from the mac that did install the app previously (click on "I" icon, then drag the provisioning profile icon on the desktop)

[image: click on "I" icon, then drag the provisioning profile icon on the desktop]

2. copy the provisioning profile to new mac and open it in Xcode (double click).

Xcode on new mac will update provisioning, allowing installation on the device without any other action and without losing any saved data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case first I was using two different teams.

The build in the device was built using `Team A`(Signing & Capabilities) and I was trying to reinstall the build using `Team B` without deleting the previous build. Changing back to `Team A` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is solved easily by removing you previous app from your device. And start to reinstall again. This works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to delete the old app on the device and reinstall it since you dont always to change the bundle id or provisioning profiles

Answer (score -1):

[image]

**Change** the build number & version and if there is previous application installed in the device make sure you delete all installed apps in the real device through

open xcode -> window -> devices