# iOS app Transfer to New Account - Documents Directory Content

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, nsdocumentdirectory, app-transfer

I have an app which saves some important files to documents directory. I am now thinking of transferring it to another account. I will be pushing a new update too when the app is transferred. I am wondering if the transfer to another account and pushing an update will affect the document directory of the app.

Looking forward,

Comment: Do you mean to change the itunes account by selling the app?

Comment: I have two accounts. I am transferring my app from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer it easily. No worries. it will not make any changes to the document directory contents of the existing app.

The app you are transferring will also carry it's associated App Id. thus app will remains the same, just the developer account is getting changed.

Read more [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f)

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey, One question regarding App Update, After app transfer (In Development Mode)
Actually Direct App Update is not possible at my end. We need to delete the older app and only then new one able to installed. Following error from Xcode
.
This application’s application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade to be allowed.

Comment: @Rahish Here is something similar, please have a look if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677133/app-installation-failed-due-to-application-identifier-entitlement

Comment: there is solution for deleting the app and reinstall it
But I don't want to delete app, as its having important info

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot,But didn't worked for me
as I have data in UserDefaults and not getting with mentioned steps

Comment: any idea how we can data from user defaults? any hack/ tool etc
its very urgent for me. Help will be appreciated