# Xcode: Unable to install "Runner" - Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

Trying to run a Flutter project in Xcode with a real iOS device but I'm receiving an error/message shown in the screenshot below.

This error occurred right after I upgraded my Flutter/dart version.

What I've tried so far:

- In Xcode -> Window -> Devices & Simulators -> Removing App from connected device.
- Uninstalling/removing the already installed app from real device.
- Clearing Xcode cache
- Renaming Bundle ID
- Made sure that the latest Xcode DeviceSupport files were up to date and matched my iPhone's current OS version (16.6)
- Provisioning Profile is manually imported (sometimes Automatically manage signing can cause issues)
- In Targets -> Runner -> Build Settings, made sure there were no errors with the Bundle ID.

Still no luck.

[image]

Details:

```
Unable to install "Runner"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
Recovery Suggestion: Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-10-13 21:29:22 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
There was an internal API error.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000067)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010bcb2c90 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 235
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010bcef2ee __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001016f1e01 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010bcef016 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1409
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010d67f7a0 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 3520
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000101827a09 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010182851d __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 196
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81257e7fb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81257fa44 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff812585ac4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 694
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff8125865b4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff812590ad7 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 762
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8126fbce3 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8126fac67 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.6.1 (20G81)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 15270;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402653081";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.2.1 (Build 22D68)
Xcode 14.2 (21534) (Build 14C18)
Timestamp: 2023-10-13T17:29:22-04:00
```

Running my real iOS device on VSCode also hasn't been successful, here's the error message:

```
No Provisioning Profile was found for your project's Bundle Identifier or your 
device. You can create a new Provisioning Profile for your project in Xcode for 
your team by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again

It's also possible that a previously installed app with the same Bundle 
Identifier was signed with a different certificate.

For more information, please visit:
  https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem could have many solution, I tried the `flutter run` command and it worked for me.
You can find a solution in this similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390132/flutter-unable-to-install-runner-error-when-trying-to-install-flutter-app-to).

Comment: I've tried all solutions on the link you've provided, no luck so far.

Comment: Try to `flutter clean` & `flutter run` and try to run it from vscode instead, make sure your phone is selected.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but still no luck on my end. Running in visual studio code does provide more information: - No Provisioning Profile was found for your project's Bundle Identifier or your 
device. - Which is odd because in Targets -> Runner -> Signing & Capabilities, I clearly have a Provisioning Profile already set up.

Comment: I saw your update to the problem, in vscode it gives exactly the problem source and the steps to fix it, sometimes it may not fix it maybe because you didn't select the right dev team for the app, sometimes it gives this error because you didn't pay the appstore, sometimes with ``Bundle Identifier`` in xcode, I don't know if you know what's a Bundle Identifier its like this ``com.example.myapp``. If you follow the steps that vscode error gives and it didn't work, it maybe a xcode problem. Maybe you can find a solution [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/28666)