# Xcode won't install specific app on specific device

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have weird problem. I can't instal unity app on a device. What weird about it is I can't install only specific app on specific device. I can install the same app on different iPad or different app on this specific device.
Every time when i tried install this app iPad is always busy.

iOS vesrion is 15.3.1
xCode 13.2.1
Unity 2020.3.x

This is detals from xcode:

```
Details

Unable to install "Peekaboo"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402652994
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-02-22 13:19:23 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
This application’s application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade to be allowed.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402652994
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE80000BE)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001137debec DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011381a3f4 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 160
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010419f94c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011381a144 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1312
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001136e3a60 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 2908
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001042ca66c __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001042cbc58 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 564
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001891a8e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001891aabac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001891b2330 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001891b2ea4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001891bd708 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000189365304 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000189364018 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPad13,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.3.1 (19D52)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 47572;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402652994";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 0;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 3;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.2";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--

Blockquote

System Information

macOS Version 12.2 (Build 21D49)
Xcode 13.2.1 (19586) (Build 13C100)
Timestamp: 2022-02-22T14:19:23+01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got an existing version of the app installed on that device, but you have since changed identifiers? If so, try deleting it, then deploy again and see what happens

```
This application’s application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade to be allowed.
```

Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain

Comment: Thanks for respond. No there isn't any of this version on device.

Comment: Have a look at this thread, it sounds similar in behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677133/app-installation-failed-due-to-application-identifier-entitlement